# How to use the EOMONTH DAX to get the last date of iso month?

Tags: powerbi

ISO months start and end at various dates. Not necessarily 1st/31st.

How to use the EOMONTH DAX to get the last date of iso month?

Comment: I think you are confusing iso month and iso week.

Comment: For example: January started on 2nd Jan and ended on 29th Jan.

Comment: That's ISO weeks 1 to 4. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) doesn't re-define months. January always has 31 days. And the ISO week date for 2023-01-01 was 2022-W52-7 - no months involved. But maybe you are interested in the first Monday and last Sunday within a month?

Comment: I have a calendar table that classifies Jan as 02Jan to 29Jan, Feb as 30Jan to 26Feb. Can EOMONTH dax handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

DAX can handle everything that follows a certain logic.

In your example Jan is week 1-4, Feb is 5-8 and Mar is probably 9-12. But April has to be 13-17 (5 weeks), which ends on Apr-30? After all 52 weeks divided by 4 is 13 not 12. So some "months" have to have 5 weeks instead of 4.

I'm afraid EOMONTH is not familiar with your calendar preferences as long as they not defined in any ISO regulation.

However, as mentioned above, it's possible to find the first Monday and last Sunday within a month using DAX, but not with the EOMONTH function.